# how reuse a like model in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 models named "posts" and "status" and want to implement likes in them. first of all, I want the like to be able to record data like timestamps and other stuff depending on how it grows, which is why I made "like" be a model of its own.

The issue is since "posts" and "status" two models of their own are going to have "like" functionality.

Is there a way I could reuse the "like" model, instead of creating a separate "like" model for "posts" and "status", or how would you personally implement something like this?

Below is the post model

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

below is the status model

```
const statusSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    tags: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: True,
        ref: 'User'
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

here is the like model which I would like users to be able to like both posts by users and statuses, while still able to retain information like the time it was liked and other information depending on the growth and need

```
const likeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    likedObject: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Posts'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})
```

Is there a way I could reuse the "like" model, instead of creating a separate "like" model for "posts" and "status" to capture the users and the time that they liked other user's statuses and posts?

Answer (score 0):

Making **Like** Model was over complicating the entire thing so you could have something like this in your postSchema.

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    timeStamps:true,
    //Adding the like property in each post but setting it to a default of 0
    likes:{type:Number, default:0}


})
```

**Now the key is identifying the post when like button is smashed**

So what you could do on the client side is making sure that when like button is clicked you have an ID of the post to the function that your calling and, then pass that ID back to the server and you can have a logic like this below on your server and you would be able to add like functionality..

**Server logic for adding like functionality**

```
router.post("/api/likes/:id", async (request, response) => {
  const post_id = request.params.id;
  const post = await postModel.findOne({ _id: post_id });

  post.likes += 1;

  const updateDocument = await postModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: post_id },
    post,
    {
      new: true,
    }
  );

  return response.status(201).json({ msg: "Liked post" });
});
```

So the idea is two always be updating that specific document

Comment: sorry but this is not the question I asked, I explained the reason I made it its own model. Please, read the question well so you can understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Quick question do you want to keep timestamp of every like? Or the recent like?

Comment: yes i want to keet tiestamp plus if it grows i can try get more data over time

Comment: Okay, since you said that one should mention how the would solve this problem... Here is my take still I would use the approach that I did in my answer but then now the structure of the like property should be an array of objects where by when someone hits the like button on the client side all you have to do is append and object of timestamp but then the length of that array ought to give you the total number of likes and you also have the data that you want i.e TimeStamp